# Background Location Service Oreo

Tags: android, location, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to find a solution for my problem. The problem is that I am trying to start a background service in Oreo in order to retrieve locations. I have seen this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits but I am trying to find a solution for this.

When I startforeground service I see this: (IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service) exception, because I am trying to retrieve locations for the next 3 minutes

Comment: Use `Foreground Service`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Adding a [mcve] to your question would probably help you to get better  answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Using a foreground service is **not** a solution in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that we cannot start a foreground service in SDK>= Oreo, because Android tries to improve the life battery. So the system kills any service (either Background or Foreground).